# How to extract a subsection of a keras.Model into another model (tensorflow 2.1.0)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I want to be able to extract a contiguous range of sublayers of my Keras model into a separate submodel. A simple example which reproduces the error I'm running into is below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input 

inp = Input(shape=(128))
d1 = Dense(128, name='d1')(inp)
d2 = Dense(128, name='d2')(d1)
d3 = Dense(128, name='d3')(d2)
out = Dense(128, name='d4')(d3)

model = Model(inp, out)
inp_d2 = model.get_layer('d2').input
sub_model = Model(inp_d2, model.output)
```

This raises:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 128), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by declaring an empty Sequential sub model and adding layers to it while iterating over the subset of original layers:

```py
# Original Model:
inp = Input(shape=(128))
d1 = Dense(128, name='d1')(inp)
d2 = Dense(128, name='d2')(d1)
d3 = Dense(128, name='d3')(d2)
out = Dense(128, name='d4')(d3)

model = Model(inp, out)

# Sub Model
sub_model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# I will skip inp and d1:
for layer in model.layers[2:]:
  sub_model.add(layer)

# Print summary:
example_input_shape = (1, 128)
sub_model.build(example_input_shape)
print(sub_model.summary())
```

Best of luck!

Comment: What if the model isn't sequential?